# Can't install libffi-devel

Tags: yum, rhel

I am trying to install libffi-devel on RHEL, but when I try I get this message:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package libffi-3.0.5-1.el5.6.z.x86_64 (which is newer than libffi-3.0.5-1.el5.i386) is already installed
```

I am running this command:

```
sudo yum install -y libffi-devel
```

And here is the full output of the command:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Excluding Packages from Rackspace - RHEL (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64) - Common
Finished
Excluding Packages from Rackspace - RHEL (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64) - MySQL 5.1
Finished
Excluding Packages from Rackspace - RHEL (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64) - PHP 5.2
Finished
Excluding Packages from Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)
Finished
Excluding Packages from Red Hat Network Tools for RHEL Server (v.5 64-bit x86_64)
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libffi-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.5-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libffi = 3.0.5-1.el5 for package: libffi-devel
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libffi.i386 0:3.0.5-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                               Arch                                                            Version                                                              Repository                                                     Size
================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 libffi-devel                                                          x86_64                                                          3.0.5-1.el5                                                          epel                                                           16 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libffi                                                                i386                                                            3.0.5-1.el5                                                          epel                                                           21 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total size: 37 k
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  package libffi-3.0.5-1.el5.6.z.x86_64 (which is newer than libffi-3.0.5-1.el5.i386) is already installed

Error Summary
-------------
```

Comment: glad i wasn't the only one with this problem! :) luckily finding this post helped me solve it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like you already have a version of `libffi-3.0.5-1.el5.6.z.x86_64` installed on your system. Check with the command and remove the rpm first.

```
rpm -qa | grep libffi
rpm -e <rpm from the above>
```

Then try installing using:

```
sudo yum install -y libffi libffi-devel
```

Comment: been searching for a while for a solution to this. Thanks!!

Comment: I was trying to remove libffi but it says error: Failed dependencies:
 libffi.so.5()(64bit) is needed by (installed) python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64